# Run .aspx page, which is 'Added as Link'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I created a project in Visual Studio named '**MyProject**', and Added .aspx file to it named '**MyPage.aspx**'.

Now, I created another project in that same solution named '**NewProject**'.
I added '**MyPage.aspx**' from '**MyProject**', to new Project, using Add as link option.

[image]

[image]

Now if I make '**NewProject**' as startup project, and '**MyPage**' from '**NewProject**' as Startpage, then it says **The resource cannot be found**.

How to achieve this?

**EDIT**: Consider that MyPage from MyProject is fetching displaying a Value from Database 'abc'. The connection string for database 'abc' is defined in Web.config of Myproject 
Now I want created another project, wherin I want the same functionality as that of MyPage, only if I want to fetch data from database 'xyz' and not database 'abc'. I shall do that by adding my connection String for 'xyz' in NewProject

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to do this?

Comment: It seems ur taking shorcuts as existing items.. instead take the exact aspx file.

Comment: Just saw your edit. I think you're using the wrong aproach for what you're trying to achieve. If you need to have 2 web projects with a different database, just deploy it twice with a different connection string. If you don't need 2 web projects, just add another connection string and add some logic to determine which one you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add project reference from 'MyProject' to NewProject through add reference.

If using IIS 7 or IIS 7.5 you can use

```
<system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument>
    <files>
      <clear />
      <add value="MyPage.aspx" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/defaultDocument

or you can try as in global.ascx

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Url.AbsolutePath.EndsWith("/"))
        {
            Server.Transfer(Request.Url.AbsolutePath + "MyPage.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```